# Process data from several sources in reactive environment of R-shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I am reading into Shiny app several data frames from various sources and formats. After processing these input data I am creating ~10 final data frames which I am displaying to the users in a form of tables or charts. So far so good.
My troubles started when I was trying to solve the problem regular update of the data. I need to upload all raw data every say 1 day and process them, so the final actualized report can be displayed to the users. No user inputs are allowed in this app, so no input widgets are employed.
Here I got trapped in the reactive environment of Shiny, trying different ways of implementation but always with errors...
My simplified code in App.R

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)
library(readxl)

# source the file with script
source("global.R")


ui <- fluidPage(
    tableOutput("table"),
)



server <- function(input, output) {

  output$table <- renderTable({

    # make sure that output is updated too
    autoInvalidate()
    # display the result data frame
    head(df())

  })

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Because the original app is relatively complex, I am using doing the data scrapping and cleaning in global.R file

```
# create a reactive timer
  autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(3000, NULL)

  # we wrap all the content that should get dynamically updated 
  # into the reactive environment to make sure that not only all external
  # data sources are updated, but also the code which alters the data further
  observe({

    autoInvalidate()



    # the first source of data
    data <- reactiveVal({
      read_csv(
        url(
          "some_my_url"),
        col_select = c(2, 3, 4) # some changes on data structure
      ) %>% rename(country = 1)
      })


    # second source of data
    data2 <- reactiveVal({
      read_excel("1.xlsx") %>% rename(country = 1)
      })


    # the final data frame
    df <- reactive({
      left_join(
        data(),
        data2(),
        by  = "country")
      })

    # Here I am doing more operation on data from several other sources,
    # but this is not important for the core of our problem


})
```

Where is the problem please? I am lost in that reactive environment of Shiny ...:)
Many thanks in advance.

I tryed implementation of the code many times in many forms but with no success..

Comment: If the data changes daily, why do you auto-invalidate every 3 seconds? If the data is in your `1.xlsx` file, you could use `shiny::reactiveFileReader` to check periodically to see if the file has been updated and re-read it; if your data is all scraped, you might consider using `cachem` or another easy caching mechanism with an expiration policy so that you only query for it daily (or half-daily, etc). If the data is to be reactive, it seems odd to place the process in `global.R` and not in `server.R` where it can check periodically.

Comment: Also, nesting `reactive`s (everything inside an `observe`) is unlikely to work out well.  rather, simply add a reference to your `autoInvalidate` within every other reactive that needs to update.  That appears to be simply `data` and `data2`.  As an aside, it's bad practice to use the name of a built-in function as the name of one of your objects.

Answer (score 0):

@r2evans , @Limey , many thanks for your comments.

I found the solution, here it is.
Just to recap, I want to regularly update all data from external data sources, perform cleansing and all operation I want and display them to users. This all in a single global session, no user interaction.

Option 1:
wrap a reactive timer and everything in a single observe()

```
# create a reactive timer
 autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(3000, NULL)

 observe({

   autoInvalidate()

# the first source of data
data1 <- reactive({read_csv("countries.csv") %>% rename(country = 1)})


# second source of data
data2 <- reactive({read_excel("1.xlsx") %>% rename(country = 1)})


# the final data frame
my_df <- reactive({
  left_join(
    data1(),
    data2(),
    by  = "country")
})

})
```

Option 2:
insert reactive timer into each reactive()

```
# create a reactive timer
autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(3000, NULL)

  # the first source of data
  data1 <- reactive({
    autoInvalidate()
    read_csv("countries.csv") %>% rename(country = 1)
  })

  # second source of data
  data2 <- reactive({
    autoInvalidate()
    read_excel("1.xlsx") %>% rename(country = 1)
  })


  # the final data frame
  my_df <- reactive({
    autoInvalidate()
    left_join(
      data1(),
      data2(),
      by  = "country")

})
```